# D'Alembertian $\Box$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds

This question has to do with the D'Alembertian operator on a general manifold with a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

I understand that the definition of the D'Alembertian is 
$$\Box \phi\equiv g_{\mu\nu}\partial^\mu\partial^\nu \phi$$
So why is it also given in the form $$\Box \phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu(\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu \phi)$$where $g=$det$(g_{\mu\nu})$? I don't understand how the $\sqrt{-g}$ factors come about in the second equation. Could someone kindly point it out?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Carry out the differentiation in the second equation using:
$$g = \epsilon_{\mu_0\ldots\mu_n}\epsilon_{\nu_0\ldots\nu_n}g^{\mu_0\nu_0}\ldots g^{\mu_n\nu_n}$$